# Any good online alternative for "Handbook of Korean Vocabulary"

Tags: vocabulary, hanja

I am referring to this book titled "Handbook of Korean Vocabulary: A Resource for Word Recognition and Comprehension":

[https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Korean-Vocabulary-Recognition-Comprehension/dp/0824818156](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824818156)

So far, I have found this book to be the best resource for non-Koreans trying to learn Korean.

I tried using Naver hanja dictionary this way by looking up each word's constituent hanja's but it does not come close to the book. Naver is too Korean native speaker oriented and gives you lot's of complicated definition's and not as user friendly as the book.

The reason why the book is so good is that it includes a lot of other words that happen to have the same morphemes and this way, it is much easier to learn Korean words. If you did not understand what I explained here, then I recommend you to find this book and just have a look. It is just amazing!!!

So, is there any good online alternative to this book?

Comment: What use case did you have in mind - just browsing? Or making yourself flashcards? (and another question - do you happen to have an android phone ?: )

Comment: yes, I actually frequently need this for every new word. Learning new words is much easier if you know the morpheme's meanings. I have made a corresponding addition in the post as to why the book is so good and special. Yes I also have an android phone :)

Comment: If you have an android phone you might be interested in trying [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=taebongsoft.hanjaobuilder) (a bit 'amateur', but no strange permissions, ads, etc!) or my [anki deck](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1500632042).

Comment: I have already downloaded and am using your app. My recommendation is to put similar words together like: 동네, 동료, 동생 etc, so that the person learning these words creates automatic mind map. Actually this is the greatest part of the book that I mentioned. These kinds of mind maps stay with you automatically

Comment: thanks for the recommendation - if I ever get more time to develop it I'll look into it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Handbook of Korean Vocabulary* is a great book, and I can't think of an online resource that's quite like it. For looking up words, [CJKV dict](https://cjkv-dict.com) might be worth a look, as it explains the characters well.

e.g. for **전화**:

[image]

Comment: thanks, indeed there seems no other resource like the book